# rerun migrations on django 1.8

Tags: django, django-models

I've got a Zinnia install in my django 1.8 python 3.4 app that is throwing errors. I'm wondering if something changed in the model from when I intially ran the migration. However, I can't see to figure out how to start over and run the migration fresh.

These are the warnings I see when I try to do a makemigrations

WARNINGS:
zinnia.Entry.categories: (fields.W340) null has no effect on ManyToManyField.
zinnia.Entry.related: (fields.W340) null has no effect on ManyToManyField.
No changes detected

I see documentation on squashmigrations makemigrations and migrate. Is there a best practice way to remove migrations and start over fresh?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to drop the db.
If you're using postgres,
then simply login to postgres account and `dropdb <db>` and run migration again.

Another way is to flush the db.
You can do this by `./manage flush` which will flush all the data in your db.

If you're using sqlite3 then, just remove db.sqlite3 from your project root.

Comment: I deleted the db from the folder and run makemigrations and I get this:

Comment: You can remove 'null=True' on ManyToManyField categories in your class